# lint checking options for compiling java using gradle

Tags: gradle, lint

```
gradle 2.2
java version 1.7.0_79
```

Hello,

I have been trying to find a list of all lint compiler options to use when compiling my java libraries.

My `build.gradle` file snippet looks like this:

```
options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:unchecked' << '-Xlint:deprecation'
```

However, I would like to check for `unused imports` and other options.

Is there any list of all the lint options and explanations?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the list from `javac --help-extra` from version 11 the output is

```
  -Xlint:<key>(,<key>)*
        Warnings to enable or disable, separated by comma.
        Precede a key by - to disable the specified warning.
        Supported keys are:
          all                  Enable all warnings
          auxiliaryclass       Warn about an auxiliary class that is hidden in a source file, and is used from other files.
          cast                 Warn about use of unnecessary casts.
          classfile            Warn about issues related to classfile contents.
          deprecation          Warn about use of deprecated items.
          dep-ann              Warn about items marked as deprecated in JavaDoc but not using the @Deprecated annotation.
          divzero              Warn about division by constant integer 0.
          empty                Warn about empty statement after if.
          exports              Warn about issues regarding module exports.
          fallthrough          Warn about falling through from one case of a switch statement to the next.
          finally              Warn about finally clauses that do not terminate normally.
          module               Warn about module system related issues.
          opens                Warn about issues regarding module opens.
          options              Warn about issues relating to use of command line options.
          overloads            Warn about issues regarding method overloads.
          overrides            Warn about issues regarding method overrides.
          path                 Warn about invalid path elements on the command line.
          processing           Warn about issues regarding annotation processing.
          rawtypes             Warn about use of raw types.
          removal              Warn about use of API that has been marked for removal.
          requires-automatic   Warn about use of automatic modules in the requires clauses.
          requires-transitive-automatic Warn about automatic modules in requires transitive.
          serial               Warn about Serializable classes that do not provide a serial version ID. 
                             Also warn about access to non-public members from a serializable element.
          static               Warn about accessing a static member using an instance.
          try                  Warn about issues relating to use of try blocks (i.e. try-with-resources).
          unchecked            Warn about unchecked operations.
          varargs              Warn about potentially unsafe vararg methods
          preview              Warn about use of preview language features
          none                 Disable all warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `build.gradle` files of all your modules as

```
  android {
    lintOptions {      
    quiet false
    abortOnError true
    ignoreWarnings true
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
   ...
          }
```

To run `lint`

```
cd PATH_TO_PROJECT
chmod a+x gradlew
./gradlew lint
```

This will work.To add any exceptions , create a `lint.xml` file inside that particular module and edit it as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
<issue id="GIVE_THE_ID_OF_ISSUE"  severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

**EDIT**

You have to add a gradle plugin for `organizeImports`.
In you main `build.gradle` add

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
   maven {
   url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
}
              }
 dependencies {
   classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-imports:1.0.1'
              }
}

 apply plugin: "org.ajoberstar.organize-imports"
```

Then you can do

```
./gradlew organizeImports
```

This will do the trick.More on [Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.ajoberstar.organize-imports) and[GitHub](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-imports)

Comment: this has nothing to do with Android. I am just creating a java library and using gradle as my build file. I was just wondering was there a lint option to find all `unused import' statements.